# Cloud Functions IPv6 connection issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I run Express app with the Firebase/Cloud Functions. Some of my app users have problems connecting to the Firebase server when the APN is set to IPv6 on their phones (mobile network). After changing phone setting to IPv4 or IPv4/IPv6 or switching to WiFi they can connect again.

I couldn't find any solutions regarding Express apps running on Firebase/Cloud Functions.

What can I do to make the IPv6 connections work?

Comment: We’re seeing the same issue.  It started about 8 days ago when our ATT users started seeing the issue. When they switch to WiFi which uses IPv4 they can connect to the Firebase functions with no issues.  Hopeful that Google can resolve this soon.  I did notice they made a DNS change to cloudfunctions.net about 10 days ago.

Comment: Good to know it's not just me. I have reported this issue to google. Hope they answer soon.

Comment: Hey, has this issue been fixed for you?

Comment: Hi, after improving the connection script a bit and adding [request timeout](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-timeout.html) the issue is gone. I am not exactly sure what was causing it. Please try the timeout and let me know if this helped you. If not we can compare the code  as I am interested to know what was causing this issue.

Comment: Hey, glad to know that the issue is gone for you Dave, it shouldn't raise any more issues for you and @Adam, I was just making sure that you both aren't affected by this anymore. Let me know.